# Does anyone know where to get the old 1.X Openni versions?

Tags: openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since openni.org has been shut down I'm not sure where to go.  I'm looking for whatever is the last stable one, 1.5.4 the last time I checked.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/164381/does-anyone-know-where-to-get-the-old-1.x-openni-versions?/) by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 429 on 2014-05-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The OpenNI sdk is on github...you could download the source for one of [the releases](https://github.com/OpenNI/OpenNI/releases).

If you're looking for older versions of NITE or the OpenNI sensor driver, I have access to some old copies of those. Feel free to send me an email and we can work something out.

**EDIT**

As of November, 2017 [this site](http://openni.ru/openni-sdk/openni-sdk-history-2/index.html) has legacy versions of most of the OpenNI packages.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2014-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [giantec](https://answers.ros.org/users/32622/giantec/) on 2017-11-14**:
hi, i also looking the old version of openni and nite, can i send you my email, i dont know if you still have access to some copies of those thanks.

**Comment by [giantec](https://answers.ros.org/users/32622/giantec/) on 2017-11-14**:
hi, i also looking the old version of openni and nite, can i send you my email, i dont know if you still have access to some copies of those thanks. omargian@hotmail.com

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2017-11-14**:
A bunch of old versions are available here: http://openni.ru/openni-sdk/openni-sdk-history-2/index.html